# Derivative of matrix inverse w.r.t. vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

I need to differentiate the inverse of the $K\times K$ symmetric matrix $A$ w.r.t some vector (that $A$ depends on). Is there a rule for this? In case I do the derivative w.r.t. to some scalar there's this rule that 
$DA^{-1}= -A^{-1}*DA*A^{-1}$.

Is this also valid in case of derivative w.r.t. vector or if not is there something equivalent?

Thanks!

Comment: You can not derive a matrix with respect to a vector

Comment: @AhmadBazzi The verb form of *derivative* is actually *differentiate*. When one *derives* something, he extrapolates it only from rudiments and shows it is true.

Comment: What is the particular matrix you are trying to differentiate?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of rules for differentiating matrices by vectors or scalars by looking up "Matrix calculus".

A list of such rules is available on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus) in the "Identities" section.

Answer (score 0):

Consider some function $A:u=[u_1,\cdots,u_k]^T\in \mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow A(u)=[a_{i,j}(u)]\in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and let 
$$f:u\rightarrow (A(u))^{-1}.$$

Then $Df_u:h=[h_1,\cdots,h_k]^T\in\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow -A^{-1}(u)DA_u(h)A^{-1}(u)\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, where $DA_u(h)=[b_{i,j}(h)]\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ (a linear application in $h$) is defined by

$b_{i,j}(h)=\sum_{p\leq k} \dfrac{\partial a_{i,j}(u)}{\partial u_p}h_p\in\mathbb{R}$.